# SLComposeViewController setInitialText not working on Twitter in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am creating a `SLComposeViewController` of type `SLServiceTypeTwitter` and I'm adding an `url` and `text` to it. However, the text is not shown, only the `url`.

Does anybody know why `SLComposeViewController's` `setInitialText` is not working on `Twitter` in `iOS 11`?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
SLComposeViewController *twPostSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
[twPostSheet setInitialText:copy];
[twPostSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

UIViewController *controller = RCTPresentedViewController();
twPostSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    // Shared with success
};
[controller presentViewController:twPostSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is intended. You should use [Twitter iOS kit](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios). With it you can share Tweets with text, URLs, photos and video. The same goes for Facebook share.